# Help Solving A Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

The following sum

$$\frac{7}{n}\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{7}{n}\right)^2}+\frac{7}{n}\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{14}{n}\right)^2}+ \cdots+\frac{7}{n}\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{7n}{n} \right)^2}$$

is a Riemann sum with $n$ subintervals of equal length for the definite integral

$$\int f(x)\,dx$$

where $b =$

and $f(x) =$

The integration should be $b \to 0$ but I couldn't figure it out.  I solved for $b$ which I got $b=7$ and then solved for $f(x)$ which was $f(x)=\sqrt{49-(x-7)^2}$.  I got $b$ correct and $f(x)$ wrong.  I used [this](https://socratic.org/questions/the-following-sum-7-6-n-2-6-n-7-612n-2-6-n-7-6n-n-2-6-n-is-a-right-riemann-sum-w) to help solve.  Here is all my rough work:
[image: rough work]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}&\sqrt{(49-\left(\frac{7}{n}\right)^2}\left(\frac{7}{n}\right)+\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{14}{n}\right)^2}\left(\frac{7}{n}\right)+\ldots+\sqrt{49-\left(\frac{7n}{n}\right)^2}\left(\frac{7}{n}\right)\\&=\left( \frac7n\right)\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{49-\left( \frac{7i}{n}\right)^2} \end{align}

You have managed to identified that $\Delta x= \frac{7}{n}$

Hence we have $$\left( \frac7n\right)\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{49-\left( \frac{7i}{n}\right)^2} =\Delta x \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{49-(i\Delta x)^2}$$

Can you identify $f$ now?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realized that I was supposed to use the lower part of the limit for the function.  So $f(b+\Delta x)$ should be $f(0+\Delta x)$ therefore the final function was $f(x)=\sqrt(49-x^2)$